# Update CDN links in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, cdn

I'm using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org) in one of my projects. In addition to the core `angular.js` file, I have several AngularJS components listed in my HTML, all served from [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

AngularJS is updated very frequently, which is great. What's not great is manually editing the version number for every URL with every update.

**Is there a way to update all these version numbers with a single command?**

It would be **amazing** if the solution could update, not only Angular, but jQuery and other CDN components.

I'm adopting [Bower](http://bower.io) and [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) in my project; if these tools can help, I'd very much like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will be in sync with the last version of the project you can use:

jQuery latest:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

Angular:
http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js

...

Google CDN doesn't implement this *latest* feature.

If you want to update versions by yourself you can use a template render in your grunt build process. https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-mustache-render for example. Keep a config file with versions per library and a template with your file and the *gaps* to be rendered in the html file.

Comment: Well-rounded answer. I like the mustache recommendation. I don't want to use the 'latest' feature in production because of the frequency of AngularJS breaking changes, but it's good to know for development.